# Removing an element from an array when a pair is found

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, for-loop

This function is made to flip the cards in my memory game and it takes care of finding the pairs. I'm trying to refresh the board by removing the pairs when they are found. Let's say i got 6 cards and that the letter "A" is found. It should then remove the pair "A" from the board and randomize the location of the other 4 cards that are left. This is one of the if statement in my function:

```
if(memoireValeur[0] == memoireValeur[1]){
                tempoArray.push(memoireValeur);
                carteFlip += 2;
                sum+=score;
                alert("Player 1: " +sum);

                for(var i=0;i<memoireArray.length;i++){
                    for(var j=0;j<memoireArray.length;j++){
                        if(memoireArray[i]==tempoArray[j]){
                            memoryArray=memoireArray.splice(i,1);

                        }
                    }
                }   
                document.write(memoryArray);
```

Let's say that the cards are "A","A","B","B","C","C". The pair "A" is selected then this part of the function will remove the "A" from the board/screen and will leave the other 2 letter on the board. The problem is that document.write(memoryArray) is suppose to show "B""B""C""C" but it isn't.

Comment: I think you should say `memoireArray.splice(i,1);` `memoryArray=memoireArray.splice(i,1);` try and let me know.

Comment: Didn't read the whole thing yet, but you're missing a bracket `}` unless you forgot to copy it. it is the bracket which is supposed to close the first one.

Comment: Mritunjay it didnt make a difference when i changed it to memoireArray.splice(i,1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issues are that:

1. You are pushing an array of values into the tempoArray variable (on line 2),
2. Using the wrong array length to loop over.
3. Splice changes the original array, don't use the return value

Fixed code:

```
if (memoireValeur[0] == memoireValeur[1]) {
    tempoArray.push(memoireValeur[0]); // changed
    carteFlip += 2;
    sum += score;
    alert("Player 1: " + sum);

    for (var i = 0; i < memoireArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tempoArray.length; j++) { //changed
            if (memoireArray[i] == tempoArray[j]) {
               memoireArray.splice(i, 1); // changed, splice changes the original array, no need to copy the return value

            }
        }
    }
    document.write(memoireArray);
}
```

A simpler way of doing this would probably be something like this:

```
if (memoireValeur[0] == memoireValeur[1]) {
    tempoArray.push(memoireValeur[0]);
    carteFlip += 2;
    sum += score;
    alert("Player 1: " + sum);

    memoryArray = memoireArray.filter(function(v) {
        return tempoArray.indexOf(v) == -1; // Keep any value in memoireArray that is not in tempoArray.
    });

    document.write(memoireArray);
}
```

Comment: The document.write(memoryArray) still shows the original elements and not the new array

Comment: I added an extra line into your fixed code tempoArray.push(memoireValeur[1]); and chanced the document.write(memoryArray) to document.write(memoireArray) and it worked. Thx

Comment: Yes, you are correct in changing it to `document.write(memoireArray)` but the `tempoArray.push(memoireValeur[1]);` should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here. What I get could be the problem

```
 memoryArray=memoireArray.splice(i,1);
```

`splice` changes the actual array on which you are calling the function. And it returns the spliced elements as array.

So if you have something like bellow

```
var arr = ['A','B','A','B']
arr = arr.splice(2,1); // value of arr will be ['A'] not ['A','B','A']
```

If you want  ['A','B','A'] use

```
arr.splice(2,1) //arr will have expected output
```